# How do I cycle between my monitors in Synergy?

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, synergy

I have two computers (Windows XP) running Synergy and it works great!

However, I'd like to be able to circle around, as I have 4 monitors in a row. When getting to the last screen on the right, I'd like to go back to the first on the left and the other way around.

Is there a way to do this with the user interface in 1.4.4 Beta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for

```
+----++----+ +----++----+
|Mon1||Mon2| |Mon3||Mon4|
+----++----+ +----++----+
```

You mentioned that you have only 2 computers. Mon1&2 are hooked up to the same system, I'll call it ABC. Mon3&4 are hooked up to the same system, I'll call it XYZ.

I'm running Synergy 1.3.4. My links would read:

```
0 to 100% of the left of ABC goes to 0 to 100% of XYZ.
0 to 100% of the left of XYZ goes to 0 to 100% of ABC.
0 to 100% of the right of ABC goes to 0 to 100% of XYZ.
0 to 100% of the right of XYZ goes to 0 to 100% of ABC.
```

Comment: Thanks! That's working fine. However, the beta 1.4.4 has a nice GUI where you can drag the screens around. I think I'll downgrade to the stable version if there is no solution for this...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
section: links
     mon1:
          right = mon2
          left = mon4
     mon2:
          right = mon3
          left = mon1
     mon3:
          right = mon4
          left = mon2
     mon4:
          right = mon1
          left = mon3
end
```

Comment: OP is running XP, where there is a GUI to configure screens.